# How do I get rid of error on Win-Builder regarding package dependency?

Tags: r, r-package

I would like to submit a package on CRAN. I have checked it locally with `devtools::check()`, with github actions, and with `rhub::check_for_cran`. All pass with no errors and only minor notes about spelling. However, when I test on win-builder using `devtools::check_win_devel()` or `devtools::check_win_release()` I get an the following error:

```
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Package required but not available: 'fqadata'
```

I also wrote the `fqadata` package. I submitted it to CRAN and it was accepted (like one day ago). Do I wait for it to be available on win-builder? Is there something wrong with `fqadata`?

I had previously used the development version `fqadata` as a dependency. After it was accepted to CRAN, I reinstalled it from CRAN, and used `usethis::use_package("fqadata")` to add it as a dependency.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it sounds like you would need to wait. Perhaps win-builder only uses package binaries, which always become available a day or two later. If your package is passing on windows using r-hub, then it's probably okay to submit to cran, if you don't want to wait.